# Always send error page after next function

Tags: express

I'm in express 4.16.3.

At first, this code works fine:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

let app = express()

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('hi, express')
    next()
})

app.use(router)

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello, world")
})

app.listen(8075, function () {
  console.log('listening localhost:8072')
})
```

But when I try to set a param in `next()`:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

let app = express()

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  next('hello, express')       ----------------mark
})

app.use(router)

app.all('*', (msg, req, res) => {
    console.log(msg)
    res.send(msg)
})

app.listen(8075, function () {
  console.log('listening localhost:8072')
})
```

the response is always an error page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>hello, express</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just add a param in next function, but it seems broken express router.

What is the right way to use next() with params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it a better practice to attach your required data with `req` object before calling `next()` ?

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.data = { title: 'your sample data' };
    next();
});

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.data);
});
```

This will attach your required data with the `request` object and pass the control to the next processing pipeline(`app.all()` handler in your code).

Then you can use that object in all of the available routes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where in the Express docs this is stated, but what you're calling when you invoke `next` isn't another middleware function directly, rather telling the Express framework to call the next middleware function. A middleware function has fixed arguments passed to it, so you will only have access to the request, the response, and a function that may call the next middleware function in the chain. The only parameters this function takes is optionally the string `'route'`.

In order to pass data to the next middleware function down the line your best bet is to modify the request object or the response object.

See [Using Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) on the Express website.